# Laravel 8 - How to redirect to Login page when not logged in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 and am having trouble with redirecting the user when they are not logged in. I have found several similar questions but they are all in older versions of laravel and none of their solutions work.

I believe I am supposed to use `Route::group()` to apply the redirect to all my routes. It currently looks like this:

```
// In web.php


Route::group(, function(){
    Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('home');
    Route::get('/account', [HomeController::class, 'account'])->name('account');
    Route::get('/feedback', [HomeController::class, 'feedback'])->name('feedback');
    Route::get('/help', [HomeController::class, 'help'])->name('help');
});
```

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be using in my first parameter in the group function. I believe that I need it to look through either the session or a cookie to see if there is a logged user?

At the moment, a user is stopped from logging in if they are on the login page and type the wrong user/password so the authentication is working. However, if they manually type a url in, ex. `ip:port/help`, they will be allowed access.

I want to have all routes on the site redirect to the login page unless the user is authenticated.

My Authentication code looks like this in my LoginController.php:

```
public function doLogin(Request $request){
        DB::connection('mysql');
        $args = $request->except('_token');

        // attempt to do the login
        if (Auth::attempt($args)) {

            // validation successful!
            return redirect('home');

        } else {        

            // validation not successful, send back to form 
            return redirect('login');
        }

    }
```

My route to get to the doLogin function which is called from an html form action looks like:

```
Route::post('authenticate', [LoginController::class, 'doLogin'])->middleware('web');
```

If anyone could give any solutions or lead me on the right path, that'd be amazing. Thanks!

#### Edit: Solution!

In the parameter I was questioning about I needed to simply add the auth middleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('home');
    Route::get('/account', [HomeController::class, 'account'])->name('account');
    Route::get('/feedback', [HomeController::class, 'feedback'])->name('feedback');
    Route::get('/help', [HomeController::class, 'help'])->name('help');
});
```

Comment: Use the `auth` middleware on routes/controllers that requires the user to be authenticated. `web` serves little prupose here, because its already applied through your providers by default.

Comment: The `web` middleware is already applied to all your routes in `web.php` ... you need the `auth` middleware to redirect away non authenticated users

Comment: Do I need to configure the middleware at all or should it work as is?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you simpy needo to add the auth middleware, this way:

```
Route::group(function(){
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('home')->middleware('Auth');
Route::get('/account', [HomeController::class, 'account'])->name('account')->middleware('Auth');
Route::get('/feedback', [HomeController::class, 'feedback'])->name('feedback')->middleware('Auth');
Route::get('/help', [HomeController::class, 'help'])->name('help');
})->middleware('Auth');
```